# Python Regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to seach within a string for heading tags,I'm looking for a regular expression to find the index within the document wherever a heading tag occurs, So something like:

```
str.index('<h*>')
```

Where the * would represent only 1 character ie. 1 , 2 , 3 etc. eliminating any head tags or html tags

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `<h\d>` or `<h\d[^>]+>` if you want to match `<hn...>` (eg: it has other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

matches = re.finditer('<h[1-6]>', your_text)
for match in matches:
    print match.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is this:

```
<h.>
```

This will match `<h1>, <h2>, <hr>`, etc... If you only want to match heading tags, use:

```
<h\d>
```

Comment: Horizontal rules are not headings.